# JMS Client Problem

Tags: jboss, jms

When my JBoss server is down, my JMS client application repeatedly tries to reconnect to the JMS server. However, after a couple of failed attempts, it connects to any other available servers in the LAN. How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be resolved by setting the following property when creating the initial context

props.setProperty("jnp.disableDiscovery", "true");